# friend overloaded operator without namespace std

Tags: c++, namespaces, std, friend, extract

Just wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction. I have a friend extraction operator that works if i include namespace std; but fails if i do not. can anyone give me a hint?

```
ostream& operator << (ostream &out, coins &value)
```

this is also a friend function, so i have this in my class.h file (as a friend)
in my functions.h file (as the prototype) and in my functions.cpp file (the logic).

ive tried making it

std::ostream& operator....
std::ostream& operator std::<< (etc)

but i just cant see where im going wrong. My compiler keeps telling me 'ostream does not name a type'

thank you

Comment: Have you included `<iostream>`?

Comment: That is not an extraction operator: that's an *insertion* operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `ostream` that exists in the `std` namespace, don't do `std::<<` (that doesn't even make sense!). Try to take less of a shotgun approach to programming; that is, don't just try random things until it works. The error tells you `ostream` (unqualified) is the problem, so you have to solve that issue first.

```
#include <iostream>

struct coins
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& sink, const coins& value);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& sink, const coins& value)
{
    sink << "doing coins output";
    return sink;
}

int main()
{
    coins c;
    std::cout << c << std::endl;
}
```

This is an insertion operator, by the way, as you're inserting data to a stream. Extraction would be `>>`.

Comment: That's an interesting question. According to here(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator-free/), the non-ostream-member overload is defined in the namespace std; without using namespace std, how does the compiler know, by << you mean std::operator<<(std::ostream&, const whatever_type_reference)?

Comment: @h9uest: Argument dependent lookup.